# The absolute position is not separating the flow of the images

Tags: html, css

My thing is not working i can't figure out any errors too.As far as i know i tried to separate those mountains and cloud on different level which seems not to be working rather they're sitting beside on their parent element

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/icon2.ico">
  <title>Farhan Sadiq</title>
</head>
  <body class="body">
    <div class="top-container">
      <img class: "top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
      <h1>Farhan Sadiq</h1>
      <p><span class="underline">WebDevloper</span> and <span class="underline">GameDevloper</span></p>
      <img class: "bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
      <img src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">
    </div>
    <div class="middle-container">

    </div>
    <div class="bottom-container">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
.body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #CEE5D0;
}

.middle-container {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.bottom-container {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.bottom-cloud {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: please spend some time learning and practicing before asking. you can learn here : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: A couple of things that might help. Put your code through a validator (e.g. W3C validator). There are some errors in the HTML, use of : instead of = for example in setting the class attribute. Then use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied by who on each element. If you are still stuck please make your code into a runnable snippet so we can see the problem. This site should help you do this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Willpower-7 w3schools is not always accurate. You may like to investigate say MDN.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in the  section, the property class uses = instead of : , then what does the output you expect mean, how do you separate it?

Comment: thank you i didn't noticee the typing error xD

Comment: can you accept my answer so that everyone can know that your question has been resolved and there is a solution

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo class in the  tag. You have to change the class in this img tag class: "top-cloud" so it looks like this class="top-cloud".

Comment: thank you i didn't noticee the typing error xD